# MySQL restore from dump working on OSX but not Windows

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I have created a dump from a CloudSQL database for local development. I can successfully run the dump file to restore the database on a computer running OSX but when trying on a colleagues computer running Windows, the execution fails part way with the following error:

```
ERROR 1822 (HY000) at line 479: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'fk_name' in the referenced table 'table_name'
```

The fk in reference points to the composite primary key of the table so I'm not sure how there could be a missing index?

Here is the failing code from the dump file:

```
KEY fk_name (user_id, org_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_name FOREIGN KEY (user_id, org_id) REFERENCES table_name (user_id, org_id)
```

The OSX computer is using MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19.
The windows computer is using MySQL Ver 8.0.15 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Comment: Those look way too generic to be the actual names. But this is probably something to do with the actual names.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Move to dba.stackexchange.com where it can get more traction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, looks like it was a compatibility issue with MySQL 8.

Downgraded the Windows machine to 5.7 and all working properly now.